# phpmyadmin using exponents (eg: 1.6E32) in the limit clause for large tables

Tags: php, mysql, phpmyadmin

It's driving me nuts ! I'm sure it's something simple I'm missing but on a large table if I try to go to say page 101 then I get a MySQL error #1064 which is the standard 'There is an error ... near' but the interesting bit is the near which is 'LIMIT 1.6E23' as an example. The only way I can get to the end of a large table is to change the sort order to the auto_increment column !!

It seems pretty clear to me that this is dowm to PHP's habit of outputting larger numbers as exponents. But I can't find a reference to it anywhere, either to change the PHP config or mysqladmin config.

It must be quite common so I hope some one can help !

Answer (score 0):

Just use number_format() on your variable used for the query

```
  <?php
        $number = number_format ($number,0);
  ?>
```